# DropDownList inside an Asp.net Calendar Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to add a `DropDownList` inside a calendar day for the asp.net `Calendar` control and then to bind it to a `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

I can add the `DropDownList` inside the day I want, but I've been unable to bind it to the event. I've seen it done for a `LinkButton` inside a `Calendar` control, but nothing for a `DropDownList`.

Comment: Server-side or client-side event?

Comment: Server-side event is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In addition to the link I provided in my answer below, if it suits your needs, you may consider using a client-side event to kick off some AJAX.  Depending on what you want to actually do on the server, it might make for a better UI.

Comment: @stillsmallvoice - just interested, where did you get with this?

Comment: Thanks Jon. So basically, my calendar has two dropdownlists and a linkbutton for a selected day. Once the user selects their options, they can then hit the linkbutton save button using the article below this answer to map the event. I then used the Page.Request.Params.GetValues("ddlSample")[0]; to get the value from the dropdownlist in the link button event. Not ideal at all, but it does work. It would be a bit nicer if I didn't need the linkbutton and could just do it through the selected index changed event.

Comment: @stillsmallvoice - interesting but I think that is the only way to do this.  I don't think you can get away with what you want without using some client side scripting, but you cannot use that as you want server side events to process. I am just glad you got it rolling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this way also. take your data into one object variable and then convert its data into select tag(Dropdown list tag in html) and then add that control in your day of calendar.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    stringBuilder matrix = new stringBuilder();
    var SemList = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()                                    
                  select new
                  {
                   SemName = row.Field<string>("SemName"),
                   SemID = row.Field<string>("SemID")
                  });

    if (SemList != null)
    {
        Matrix.Append("<select ID='sem_" + dt.Rows[k]["ActualCMID"].ToString() + "' runat='server' width='100px' onchange='" + Server.HtmlEncode("javascript:BindSpecialization('" + dv.ToTable().Rows[k]["ActualCMID"].ToString() + "')").ToString() + "'>");
        Matrix.Append("<option value='0'>---Select---</option>");
        foreach (var sem in SemList)
        {
           Matrix.Append("<option value='" + sem.SemID + "'>" + sem.SemName + "</option>");
        }
        Matrix.Append("</select>");
    }
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(Matrix.ToString()));
}
```

I hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is possible I wrote up articles about imagebuttons and linkbuttons, follow the same form here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jhermiz/archive/2007/12/10/Cool-Tricks-With-The-ASP.net-Calendar.aspx

When you write your event you just need to specify the `Handle` of that event.

### Edit

After thinking about this some more this may in fact not be possible due to the way the asp.net lifecycle functions and how it handles the `DayRender` event.

Even if you do something to this effect:

```
protected void Calendar1_Render(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsWeekend)
    {
        DropDownList d = new DropDownList();
        d.ID = "bah" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString();
        d.AutoPostBack = true;
        d.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        d.Items.Add("A");
        d.Items.Add("B");
        d.Items.Add("C");
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(d);
    }
}
```

This won't work since the page load event has already fired by the time each day is rendered, so even setting `Autopostback=true` wont work.

In addition even if you assign a new `EventHandler` to the dynamic control it wont work as in this case:

`d.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(yourMethod);`

The only thing I can come up with that might work is something to this effect:

```
 protected void Calendar1_Render(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Day.IsWeekend)
            {
                DropDownList d = new DropDownList();
                d.ID = "bah" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString();
                d.Items.Add("A");
                d.Items.Add("B");
                d.Items.Add("C");
                d.Attributes.Add("onchange", "__doPostBack();");
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(d);
            }
        }
```

The issue is this doesn't fire your server event it only fires a post back, but it gives you an idea that it could fire it via some attributes and client side scripting.  Could you change your server method to be a client method?  If so this would work, you'd replace `__doPostBack()` with the name of your client side method.

Unfortunately I am not an ASP.net expert, I dab in too many other things, but this information is pretty solid when it comes to the Calendar control, I've used it a lot in the past and got to the point where I had to stop using it due to its limitations.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have actually used the article you posted in the past, great stuff. The problem is, the post deals with Images or Literals, I haven't seen a good article on how exactly to specify the handle event in a calendar control. MSDN documentation states: Because the DayRender event is raised while the Calendar control is being rendered, you cannot add a control that can also raise an event, such as LinkButton. You can only add static controls, such as System.Web.UI.LiteralControl, Label, Image, and HyperLink. I'm sure there is a way around this, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: @user - in my article the controls I add are actually imagebuttons which can cause postbacks so Im not sure which MSDN you are referring to.

Comment: Hey Jon, this is the MSDN article [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx) . I looked again at your articles, but I didn't quite see an answer to what I'm trying to do. Even though I'm setting up an event handler for the dropdownlist, its wiped out during the page cycle and I'm not sure how to do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I didn't know about this limitation, but found a workaround that involves using client-side event handling.  According to the author, it involves 1) Add a static control in the DayRender event; 2) Make it behave like a dynamic control that has events; 3) Pass data to identify which button was clicked.

Here's the link: http://www.aarongoldenthal.com/post/2009/03/31/Create-Dynamic-Buttons-in-an-ASPNET-Calendar.aspx

The example he gives involves a LinkButton, but it shouldn't be hard to modify it for the dropdown control.

Comment: Thanks, it is a good article and it does work. From the article, he sets the link.NavigateUrl to bind back to the event, what would you use for the dropdownlist onselectedchange event? I've tried added attributes, adding a selectedchange event, can't get it to work.

Comment: @user - you would add a `onchange` event in this case.  because on change will fire when the value is selected from the drop down box.

Comment: Just what @JonH said.  You have to use client side script to kick off the postback.  You won't be able to hook into the server side OnSelectedChanged that way, but that's why they're called workarounds.